# Crosstalk Question

Tags: transmission-line, inductive, sine, crosstalk, square

Could somebody explain me how could I predict the crosstalk between tracks.From what I know about this are two types of crosstalk: inductive and capacitive.Inductive from what I read is the worst.For example I know that the inductive crosstalk appears when the rise/fall time are really shorts and if the target has a big impedance on the line, but what happens when you have a sine wave instead of a square wave ?

Comment: for inductive you can try using oscilloscope,usually the pulses will undergo crosstalk (because parasitic capacitance and inductance) but to a limit that they can be resolved, but you will see as you untwist the pair the signal gets more worse the and more crosstalk occurs, eye diagrams are best to study them.Its sinc function best represent a signal pulse, a sine wave of high frequency cannot be resolved.

Comment: The only practical way to predict [at PCB design time] is to use EM simulation software for your layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both inductive and capacitive coupling get worse with faster rise/fall times.

Inter-track capacitance couples fast rising/falling voltages on one track (wire) to other tracks in the vicinity and, for magnetic coupling, the parasitic capacitance of a track to earth creates a high-current pulse in that track when dv/dt is high - this high-current pulse produces a magnetic field that couples to other circuits/tracks/wires.

To predict inductive-coupling levels requires knowledge of the mutual coupling between tracks and is quite hard to estimate or measure but there should be some pretty good examples to be found on google and it wouldn't surprise me if a few had net calculators to help. The "recipient" track's impedance is of course significant and if the track is grounded at one end (or connected to a decent voltage source) and is open circuit at the other end, the interfering voltage will be at its greatest (ignoring transmission line effects or resonant circuits being present).

Capacitive coupling is a little simpler because you can measure/predict this type of coupling a lot easier. Like the inductive coupling, high impedances to ground on the target track do not help reduce noise pick-up.

A sinewave has a maximum dv/dt when it is passing through zero - you can use this to estimate the effect of coupling between tracks.